# Inheriting user control from an other user control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 app. Is would like to have some user controls which they inherit from a specific user control. I define my parent user control like this:

public abstract class WidgetsUserControl : UserControl
{

}

and the child like:

public partial class childControl  : WidgetsUserControl 
{

}

but it get error in defining abstract which says : "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'project1.WidgetsUserControl'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This works good:
Code behind for parent user control:

    public abstract partial class WidgetsUserControl : UserControl {
        ...
        }

xaml for parent class:    
    <UserControl 
           ...
            xmlns:we="clr-namespace:project1"
            ...>

    </UserControl>

code behind for child user control:
    public partial class childControl : WidgetsUserControl {
    ...
    }

xaml for child user control:
    <we:WidgetsUserControl x:Class="project1.childControl"
       ...
        xmlns:we="clr-namespace:project1"
       ...>    
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"></Grid>
    </we:WidgetsUserControl>
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get the extended class to use it's new code-behind, I had mapped the Loaded event to a new method and it didn't work. I'm also unable to call InitializeComponent() what could be missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's complaining that you don't have the "partial" keyword in your definition of the WidgetsUserControl class.  You probably have a corresponding XAML file for WidgetsUserControl that is partially defining that class, so here, you need to specify that it is partially defined as well.

```
public abstract partial class WidgetsUserControl : UserControl
```

Please note that if you go in this direction, then you also need to make the childControl definitions consistent.  That is, in the code you would have:

```
public partial class childControl : WidgetsUserControl
```

and in the XAML, you will also need to specify that the childControl is a WidgetsUserControl, not just a simple UserControl:

```
<project1:WidgetsUserControl>
</project1:WidgetsUserControl>
```

Although this will work, a problem you will run into with this is that the Visual Studio Designer will complain that it can't create an instance of WidgetsUserControl (because it is abstract).  This makes visualizing and editing the childControl a bit difficult.  To solve this, my suggestion would be to just do away with the "abstract" in the base WidgetsUserControl.  If you really want the base class to be abstract, then see here for other suggestions:

[Abstract class in designer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/ddbc181f-dda4-48ba-94b3-194494c6b1e1/)

Comment: @ Gambit: i did what you recommended but then i got compiling error "Partial declarations of 'project1.childControl' must not specify different base classes" under public partial class childContro

Comment: This is another issue with consistency between the XAML file and the code file, but for the childControl class. I have edited the answer to note this.  I have also included another issue that you will likely encounter due to the fact that you are deriving a UserControl from an abstract base class and how to address.

Comment: @ Gambit:Thanks for your help. the <project1:WidgetsUserControl>...</project1:WidgetsUserControl> return afew errors like nested type are not supported and...so i used <we:WidgetsUserControl>...</we:WidgetsUserControl> instead and it works. I also added  xmlns:we="clr-namespace:project1" in child control.